# Python Pillow's ImageTk does not display images originating from certain file types

Tags: image, python-2.7, tkinter, python-imaging-library

Suppose I have the following code:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from tkinter import *

im = Image.open(<Some file path>)
root = Tk()
photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(im)
label = Label(root, image=photo)
label.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

When the file path is a typical file type like a png, the program will display the image as you would expect it to. However, when I give it a tga file (uncompressed Targa32 128x128), it does not show the image (just leaves a blank area). However, the image does show when using Pillow's Image.show() method, just not with tkinter.

Note that I'm only working with global variables so it can't be a garbage collection issue.

How can I get my tga files to show up in my tkinter interface?

Comment: Are you able to share the image?

Comment: It exists as a text file. [Here, it's for a battlebot game if you were wondering](https://gametechmods.com/uploads/files/5307image.zip)

Comment: It's late here, so I'll look at it tomorrow- thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Well that was shortlived. It turns out converting the image to RBG fixed it for some reason.

```
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from tkinter import *

im = Image.open(<Some file path>)
root = Tk()
photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(im.convert("RGB"))
label = Label(root, image=photo)
label.pack()
root.mainloop()
```